# Should apache ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ line be removed in production?

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi, configuration

Here is the part of my current apache config that refers to cgi-bin stuff.  This info was included in the default configuration in debian.  Should this be removed on a live/production machine?

```
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not running any CGI from /usr/lib/cgi-bin/, then it's unnecessary.  That said, it's a production machine, so tread carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be removed on a production system - unless (of course) you are actually using it. If you're not sure, it probably means that you're not using it.

Here is why: With this configuration, `cgi-bin/` points to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` and whatever is in there can be executed. It's a system directory, so what's in there usually depends on what you've installed using the system's package management system. Any software with a web interface (like some sort of monitoring or management software) might have a cgi script file there. This means that simply installing such a program is enough so that ANYONE who has access to this web server (in the case of a public web server: everyone) can access that web interface.

Suppose you've just installed some sort of system management software which has a web interface, in the shape of a cgi file in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` and it has something like "1234" as default password. To make things worse, this is on a public web server. Now, everyone can open `http://www.yourserver.com/cgi-bin/foowebadmin`, log in using "1234" and change the system configuration of your PRODUCTION server.

Of course, if you're using this feature on purpose, you will have taken care of proper security/authentication and so on, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always remove the default vhost that comes with debian from the sites-enabled directory. I also replace the apache.conf with something that is sensible for our environment.

Those a are config files and dpkg (backend to apt-get) should expect them to be changed. Tools like puppet run apt-get in a way that will keep the "old config" in case a package updates it's configuration, and if you run apt-get interactively it will ask you what to do if it detects a change in the configuration files.

That is *any change* not just a conflict that can't be merged automagically. After all even if it could be merged it could yield some configuration you don't really want in your system.

To break of a flamewar (sorry, that should really be discussed elsewhere but I just need to say it): My opinion is that even upon installing a daemon it must not be started automatically. For any decent site the default config is almost always wrong. (Yes I know that I can set dpkg options so that it won't be started, I'd rather like it to be the default)